# Скрыть пункт меню, которое появляется динамически, jquery

Tags: jquery

Скрыть пункт меню, которое появляется динамически, `jquery`.
***HTML:***

```
<span title="изменить частоту уведомлений об этой теме" class="btn-group notification-options open" data-click-outside="true">  
  <button class="widget-button btn ui blue button trackingbutton" aria-label="Уведомлять" title="Уведомлять">
     <i class="fa fa-circle-o regular" aria-hidden="true"></i>Уведомлять
  </button>
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li>
       <a>
         <span class="icon fa fa-exclamation-circle watching"></span>
         <div>
            <span class="title">Наблюдать</span>
            <span class="desc">Уведомлять по каждому новому сообщению в этой теме и показывать счетчик новых непрочитанных ответов.</span>
         </div>
       </a>
    </li>
    <li>
       <a>
          <span class="icon fa fa-circle tracking"></span>
          <div>
             <span class="title">Следить</span>
             <span class="desc">Количество непрочитанных сообщений появится рядом с названием этой темы. Вам придёт уведомление, только если кто-нибудь упомянет ваш @псевдоним или ответит на ваше сообщение.</span>
          </div>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a>
           <span class="icon fa fa-circle-o regular"></span>
           <div>
              <span class="title">Уведомлять</span>
              <span class="desc">Вам придёт уведомление, только если кто-нибудь упомянет ваш @псевдоним или ответит на ваше сообщение.</span>
           </div>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a>
           <span class="icon fa fa-times-circle muted"></span>
           <div>
             <span class="title">Без уведомлений</span>
             <span class="desc">Не уведомлять об изменениях в этой теме и скрыть её из последних.</span>
           </div>
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
<p>Вы будете получать уведомления, если кто-то упомянет ваш @псевдоним или ответит вам.</p>
```

Меню `(ul class="dropdown-menu")` добавляется динамически по нажатию .

Необходимо скрыть последний элемент меню. `hide()` не скрывает элемент, который отсутствовал и появляется динамически.

```
<script> 
$('.trackingbutton').on('click',function() {
$('.dropdown-menu').find('li:last').hide(); //не прячет этот элемент
});
</script>
```

Заранее большое спасибо.

**Уточнение.**

Изначально `.dropdown-menu` не присутствует. Он появляется по нажатию `trackingbutton`. Необходимо скрыть `li:last`. `hide()` не работает на элементе, которые появляется динамически.

Comment: <script> 
    $('.trackingbutton').on('click',function() {
        $('.dropdown-menu').find('li:last').css("visibility", "visible");
    });
</script>